# Apache Flink: checkpointing an operator that dispatches elements after a delay

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I want to relay incoming events from a stream after a certain delay. This is the code of the Flink operator that does that

```
class MessageDelayFunction[T](schedulingDelay: Int, timeUnit: TimeUnit)
  extends RichAsyncFunction[T, T] {

  // use guava's executor for periodic execution
  private var scheduledThreadPoolExecutor: ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor = _
  private var executorService: ListeningScheduledExecutorService = _


  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    scheduledThreadPoolExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(scheduledThreadPoolExecutor)
  }

  override def asyncInvoke(input: T,
                           resultFuture: ResultFuture[T]): Unit =
    // dispatch the input after the specified delay
    executorService.schedule(
      new Runnable {
        override def run(): Unit = resultFuture.complete(Collections.singletonList(input))
      },
      schedulingDelay,
      timeUnit)


  override def timeout(input: T, resultFuture: ResultFuture[T]): Unit =
    // if we incur a timeout, ignore the message
    resultFuture.complete(Collections.emptyList())
}
```

I'm running this with a `schedulingDelay = 2` and `timeUnit = timeUnit.HOURS`.

However, Flink's checkpointing fails with this operator (I verified it works fine without it). The checkpointing happens every 2 minutes with a timeout of 10 minutes. Every checkpoint simply times out and the whole node seems just "stuck" on this operator. Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do in Flink? Or any way to fix the checkpointing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flink provided timers functionality, these are check-pointed as well.

Comment: Thanks! Won't Flink overwrite the state if there are multiple incoming events before the old one could be dispatched?

Comment: No. For a given key, you can have multiple timers registered at different timestamps. If you are using awe infrastructure you can try using delay queues